# How to Modify Web.config file during custom deployment for a C# application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, deployment, web-deployment

I am creating a custom deployment script using powershell for an application that has  both, windows services and web services, as part of deployment. There are 5-6 web.config files and similar number of app.config files which are quiet big. Deployment is done on out of network non domain machines hence creating deployment using VS or Teamcity is not a choice. I thus cannot use web.config transform options. I can consider using msdeploy but right now in the advanced stage where everything is done except update of config files.

Is there a tool that can be used to provide an answer file to transform web.config and app.config? I can build one by manually specifying the XML node names and their corresponding but having a tool would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

We use MSDeploy.exe and [WebDeploy Parameterization](https://dotnetcatch.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/parameterizationpreview-visual-studio-extension/) for the deployment of web applications, windows services, scheduled tasks and SQL databases.  WebDeploy Parameterization occurs at deploy time as opposed to build time and can be used to edit all types of files (not just config files).

Using MSDeploy for non-web projects isn't as easy as using WebDeploy but all the functionality is there.  With a little bit of investment you can automate nearly anything on the Microsoft stack.